# Error 500: Mailgun's servers are currently unreachable

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

Using laravel I'm trying to send batch emails with the Mailgun api.

```
  $recipients = new Collection();
  $subscription_addresses = new Collection();
  foreach($request['subscriptions'] as $subscription){
    $recipients->put($subscription['email'], (object)array('id' => $subscription['id']));
    $subscription_addresses->push($subscription['email']);
  }

  $recipient_chunks = $recipients->chunk(500);
  $subscription_address_chunks = $subscription_addresses->chunk(500);
  
  for($i = 0; $i < count($recipient_chunks); $i++){
    $mgClient = Mailgun::create(env('MAILGUN_SECRET'), 'https://' . env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT'));
    $domain = env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN');
    $params =  array(
      'from'    => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME') . ' <' . env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') . '>',
      'to'      => $subscription_address_chunks[$i]->toArray(),
      'subject' => $request['newsletterForm']['subject'],
      'html'    => view('emails.newsletter', $request['newsletterForm'])->render(),
      'recipient-variables' => json_encode($recipient_chunks[$i], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
    );

    # Make the call to the client.
    $mgClient->messages()->send($domain, $params);
  }
```

The chunking per 500 is because Mailgun queues only 500 mails per request according their docs.

Anyway, while testing with 3 recipients, everything works fine on localhost.
However, while sending on a live domain, I get an error `Mailgun's servers are currently unreachable.`

Anybody who knows this issue? Not much to find on stackoverflow or in the mailgun docs.

The MX records and mailgun configuration should be ok since I'm able to send single mails on the live site with

```
Mail::send('emails.confirmation', $request->all(), function($message) use ($request){
    $message->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
    $message->to($request['userInfo']['email'], $request['userInfo']['firstname'] .' '. $request['userInfo']['lastname'])->subject('Uw bestelling bij Hof te Berchemveld');
  });
```

Comment: Any chance your live hosting is blacklisted by mailgun (if it's something that might have been used by spambots or something?). Maybe that's a question for mailgun

Comment: I asked there support but might take a while to get a response. It's quite urgent.

Comment: Looks to me like you have been blacklisted. Make sure your code respects all the rules. What I ended up doing is saving the mail to a temporary table and run a cron job every 1 minutes to send out the mail. So all my chunks of 400 where send out 1 minute apart. Notice that I am not sending out chunks of 500 in case my app needs to send something else like a password request or an account creation. Contact support and see if you can find out why you were blacklisted in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue & found out that my domain & sender mail domain was different. Now after resolving that issue it worked fine for me.